# this plant and its constituents can not be patented

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US20110256246](https://www.google.com/patents/US20110256246)

This is a traditional recognised and acknowledged healing plant of the Australian Aboriginals in Tasmania and other parts of Australia, it can NOT therefore be patented in part or full as it is in common use Now and has been in continual use for a minimum of a thousand of year. IT is also registered by the The pure essential oil has been registered with the Therapeutic Goods Administration (TGA) as providing temporary relief of the pain of arthritis.[14]

Answer (score 1):

The patent family contains 3 US applications, two of which were abandoned, and one was granted. The granted patent is [US9,408,883](https://www.google.com/patents/US9408883?dq=13/969623). For a prosecution history of the patent family, see http://globaldossier.uspto.gov/#/result/application/US/13090640/120486

The granted patent recites (emphasis added):

> The prior art known to the inventor includes the Kunzea ambigua
>   websites (...) (Apr. 5, 2007), which explains
>   that Kunzea ambigua has been found effective against several bacteria,
>   including Staphylococcus aureas, E. coli and Candida albicans...
>
> Australia Patent No. 721,156 B2, entitled “Essential Oil and Methods
>   of Use,” describes the use of the essential oils from Kunzea ambigua
>   for **external** applications for the treatment of medical conditions.
>
> The totality of the prior art **neither teaches nor suggests the use of
>   Kunzea ambigua... for the treatment of digestive
>   ailments and inflammatory conditions**, among other beneficial uses, as
>   taught herein.

To invalidate the patent, we need public disclosure prior to Apr 23, 2007 which show that:

1. it was known to use Kunzea ambigua in internally administered application, and/or
2. it was known that Kunzea ambigua was effective in treating digestive ailments